# connect dots of scatterm

Tags: matlab, scatter

I have very zoomed in map created with the following code (anything with lat is a latitude, anything with long is a longitude).

```
latuu=[latu1,latu2,latu3,latu4];
latvv=[latv1,latv2,latv3,latv4];
latff=[latf1,latf2,latf3,latf4];
lattt=[latt1,latt2,latt3,latt4];
lonuu=[lonu1,lonu2,lonu3,lonu4];
lonvv=[lonv1,lonv2,lonv3,lonv4];
lonff=[lonf1,lonf2,lonf3,lonf4];
lontt=[lont1,lont2,lont3,lont4];
%% Make map of the Moorings and add the points extracted by GridPointsSuper
disp=0.01;

worldmap world
load coastlines
[latcells, loncells] = polysplit(coastlat, coastlon);
plotm(coastlat, coastlon)
h = worldmap([min(latall)-disp max(latall)+disp],[min(lonall)-disp max(lonall)+disp]);%'Europe',
getm(h,'MapProjection')
geoshow('landareas.shp', 'FaceColor', [0.15 0.5 0.15])
geoshow('worldrivers.shp', 'Color', 'cyan')
hold on 
P=scatterm(PlanierCoor(1),PlanierCoor(2),'red')
textm(PlanierCoor(1),PlanierCoor(2),"Planier")
hold on
u=scatterm(latuu,lonuu,'x','b')

hold on
v=scatterm(latvv,lonvv,'x','g')

hold on
f=scatterm(latff,lonff,'x','k')

hold on
t=scatterm(lattt,lontt,'x','c')


legend([P,u,v,f,t],{'buoy','u','v','f','t'})
```

It creates the following map succesfully:[image]

I want to connect the cyan crosses so it forms a square, but when I do

```
  hold on
    t=scatterm(lattt,lontt,'-x','c')
```

it gives the error

```
Error using scatter (line 130)
There is no LineStyle property on the Scatter class.

Error in internal.mapgraph.GeoScatterGroup (line 44)
            gTemp = scatter(lon, lat, varargin{:});

Error in scatterm (line 62)
mapgraph = internal.mapgraph.GeoScatterGroup(ax, lat, lon, args{:});

Error in ExtractMooringsPlanier (line 122)
t=scatterm(lattt,lontt,'-x','c')
```

Is there a way to connect the crosses on this map? If so how?

Comment: Regarding the error, this is default behavior. (imagine if for a `scatterm` it plotted lines from all points to all points..it would be a mess!) If you want just this rectangle with the 4 vertexes why don't you plot it manually using those 4 points' coordinates? If this isn't about the rectangle but you are asking about something more general, this is not obvious (to me) from the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't found a way to do it within scatterm, but it works with plotm if you plot your first x twice.

```
latuu=[latu1,latu2,latu3,latu4];
latvv=[latv1,latv2,latv3,latv4];
latff=[latf1,latf2,latf3,latf4];
lattt=[latt1,latt2,latt4,latt3,latt1];% plot first point twice
lonuu=[lonu1,lonu2,lonu3,lonu4];
lonvv=[lonv1,lonv2,lonv3,lonv4];
lonff=[lonf1,lonf2,lonf3,lonf4];
lontt=[lont1,lont2,lont4,lont3,lont1];%

disp=0.01;
figure
worldmap world
load coastlines
[latcells, loncells] = polysplit(coastlat, coastlon);
plotm(coastlat, coastlon)
h = worldmap([min(latall)-disp max(latall)+disp],[min(lonall)-disp max(lonall)+disp]);%'Europe',
getm(h,'MapProjection')
geoshow('landareas.shp', 'FaceColor', [0.15 0.5 0.15])
geoshow('worldrivers.shp', 'Color', 'cyan')
hold on 
P=scatterm(PlanierCoor(1),PlanierCoor(2),'red')
textm(PlanierCoor(1),PlanierCoor(2),"Planier")
hold on
u=scatterm(latuu,lonuu,'x','b')

hold on
v=scatterm(latvv,lonvv,'x','g')

hold on
f=scatterm(latff,lonff,'x','k')

hold on
t=scatterm(lattt,lontt,'x','grey')

hold on
plotm(lattt,lontt,'k')

legend([P,u,v,f,t],{'buoy','u','v','f','t'})
```

You have to make sure the order in which the points are plotted is correct, otherwise the lines cross.
[image]